# Call RangeValidator on RowCommand

Tags: asp.net

I have added a Range Validator to a textbox in the editItemTemplate of my gridview.

Now, All the examples I found online have you submitted the page to get the validator to kick in, I don't want that, I want to be able to call in from the rowCommand event which is called to update the row.  Is there a way to link the RangeValidator to a button that does submit?  Can i call programmatically?

Thanks

Edit:

I did find the following, but it seems to be completely ignored:

```
GridViewRow EditRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

RangeValidator test = EditRow.FindControl("rvClass") as RangeValidator;

test.MinimumValue = "1";
test.MaximumValue = "255";
test.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
test.Validate();

if (!test.IsValid)
{
   test.ErrorMessage = "BOO!";
}                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call Validate on the RangeValidator inside the rowCommand event.

Comment: I Edited my question and added some code I tried in the rowCommand event, it seems to get ignored.

Comment: Do you have your controltovalidate property set?

Comment: and the value in the textbox is between 1 and 255?

Comment: tried both ways and even yanked the if statement all together, the validator never seems to kick off.  I put in breakpoints and it goes by it, but nothing happens

Comment: an Update:  I didn't find a way to call the validator from the rowCommand, so my work around was just to write my own validation in the rowCommand event.